# Scroll down on page load in a php file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a php file which generates a wp document. When it loads I want it to scroll down to the bottom or to a div. Here is the code I used, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
<?php echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(window).load(function() {
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $('#cuar_reply_0').offset().top }, 1000);
    });
    </script>";
?>
```

Comment: What do you mean "not work"? You should specifiy your problem and your error message or unwanted behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Use proper `quotes`. Change `$("html, body")` to `$('html, body')`:

```
<?php echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
$(window).load(function() {
$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $('#cuar_reply_0').offset().top }, 1000);
 });
</script>"; ?>
```

If you have `jQuery` library loaded and your element exists, it should work something like this:

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  $("html, body").animate({
    scrollTop: $('#cuar_reply_0').offset().top
  }, 1000);
});
```

```css
div {
  background: #adadad;
  height: 600px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
<p id='cuar_reply_0'>element</p>
```

Comment: It means that you don't have `jQuery` library included or the path to it is wrong. Put this `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` in your page, before the script with the animation. Or try `<?php echo "<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js'></script><script type='text/javascript'>
$(window).load(function() {
$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $('#cuar_reply_0').offset().top }, 1000);
 });
</script>"; ?>` just for testing.

Answer (score 0):

### JQuery on scroll Load more

```js
$(function($) {
    $('#mydiv').on('scroll', function() {
      
        if($(this).scrollTop() +          
                       $(this).innerHeight() 
                   >=  $(this)[0].scrollHeight)
         {
             alert('bottom reached ...');
             //add your ajax for load more..
         }
     })
  }
);
```

```css
#mydiv{width:150px;height:150px;overflow:auto;overflow-x: hidden;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mydiv">
Dividing the Panchatantra into individual stories</br> takes off the essence of the colourful fables. Despite this fact, Panchatantra stories have spread all over the world </br> for centuries, especially as bedtime stories for kids. We present here, a list of our versions of 60 such</br>  popular short stories from the Panchatantra, in English. The short</br>  stories include pictures and moral messages, </br> especially for kids. 

</div>
```